# Match Trades from a CSV File in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, import-from-csv

So I have a CSV File with sorted trade data. 
It has the following columns :

```
Trade_Price , TimeStamp , Buy/Sell , Contract
```

Now I have sorted the trades so that they are in the CSV in successive rows. Now I want to pair up the trades find the net PnL by taking the difference of the Trade_Price and put this in a new dataFrame in Python. I am not sure how exactly to loop through the Dataframe to match these trades and then store them in a new dataframe with the following columns.

```
Contract ,   Price_Change  ,         PnL  ,       Trade_Number

Price_Change = Trade_price(1) - Trade_price(2)
```

PnL will be if I bought at 100 and sold at 101 then my PnL will be $1 I assume trade size as 1.

Comment: Best if you parse the plain file and groubpy Contract. Then iterate over the groups... What's the Trade_Number? It comes out of thin air here...

Comment: Its just another column I add to signify the trade. Its to keep a count of the number of trades.

Comment: So I already am grouping it by contract however I am unsure How I can iterate through it and grab two rows at a time? and once that is done move onto the third row instead of the second.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you may buy into a position but you need several trades to get out of it. Trading is not a binary business. Or you may have already a position and buy again...

Comment: This is just a test so for this the CSV file already has pairs of trades. The format is that a pair of trades is listed one after the other. I want to reconcile the pair trades into one table and calculate the PnL from them.

Answer (score 0):

Two grab two columns at a time you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

Trade_Price = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,6,7,8]})
Trade_Price1 = Trade_Price.iloc[::2,:].reset_index(drop=True)
Trade_Price2 = Trade_Price.iloc[1::2,:].reset_index(drop=True)
print Trade_Price1
print Trade_Price2
print Trade_Price1-Trade_Price2 #do your operations here
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  5
1  3  7
   A  B
0  2  6
1  4  8
   A  B
0 -1 -1
1 -1 -1
```